# How to access the values inside the 'files' field in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have downloaded some files using the file pipeline and i want to get the values of the files field. I tried to print item['files'] and it gives me a key error. Why is this so and how can i do it?

```
class testspider2(CrawlSpider):
name = 'genspider'
URL = 'flu-card.com'
URLhttp = 'http://www.flu-card.com'
allowed_domains = [URL]
start_urls = [URLhttp]
rules = (
    [Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow = (),restrict_xpaths = ('//a'),unique = True,),callback='parse_page',follow=True),]
)

def parse_page(self, response):
    List = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    item = GenericspiderItem()
    date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")#get date&time dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
    MD5hash = '' #store as part of the item, some links crawled are not file links so they do not have values on these fields
    fileSize = ''
    newFilePath = ''
    File = open('c:/users/kevin123/desktop//ext.txt','a')
    for links in List:
        if re.search('http://www.flu-card.com', links) is None:
            responseurl = re.sub('\/$','',response.url)
            url = urljoin(responseurl,links)
        else:
            url = links
        #File.write(url+'\n')
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]      
        fileExt = ''.join(re.findall('.{3}$',filename))
        if (fileExt != ''):
            blackList = ['tml','pdf','com','php','aspx','xml','doc']
            for word in blackList:
                if any(x in fileExt for x in blackList):
                    pass    #url is blacklisted                               
                else:                    
                    item['filename'] = filename
                    item['URL'] = url
                    item['date'] = date
                    print item['files']
                    File.write(fileExt+'\n')
                    yield GenericspiderItem(
                        file_urls=[url]
                        )
                    yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access `item['files']` in your spider. That is because the files are download by the FilesPipeline, and items just reach pipelines after they get out of your spider.

You first yield the item, then it gets to FilesPipeline, then the files are dowloaded, an just then the field `images` is populated with the info you want. To access it, you have to write a pipeline and schedule it after the FilesPipeline. Inside your pipeline, you can access the `files` field.

Also note that, in your spider, you are yielding to different kinds of items!